# Adding style in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following piece of code in my html:

```
<p>Tags: {{source.tags}}</p>
```

This is the rendered html:

```
mq-server queue republish purge
```

This value comes from a field in my object:

```
'tags': 'mq-server queue republish purge'
```

What I want is to add style to each separated by space word, in better words something like tags, I like the [level-info](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) class in bootstrap, anyone has an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the string into separate words and the use ng-repeat to display them inside a span with the label classes

```
<span class="label label-default" ng-repeat="tag in source.tags.split(' ')">{{tag}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller could split the tags in to an array and then use ng-repeat to loop through the array, applying the label tag to each.

**split array:**

```
$scope.source.tagsArray = $scope.source.tags.split(" ");
```

**print tags in template**

```
<p>Tags: 
    <span ng-repeat="tag in source.tagsArray" class="label label-info">
        {{tag}}
    </span>
</p>
```